# SSIS SCD Wizard with multiple incoming records

Tags: sql-server, ssis

PlEASE FORGIVE.  I am very desperately looking how to ask this eloquently. Not doing to good here.

In SSIS, if you have an incoming dataset that has multiple records for the same PK (like intraday records in a daily processing method), how do I tell the SCD Wizard to expect that?

in my case, even though all of my fields are set to "Historical", they all appear as new, because they are all coming in all at the same time.

```
Example data:
BK, insertion depth, drill depth, bore depth
1, 1000, 1020, 1022
1, 1025, 1222, 1233
1, 1100, 1321, 1333
2, 1233, 1255, 1022
2, 2222, 3333, 3333
3, 1010, 900, 885
```

I get this in one report.  They all show up as new in base load.  I have a create_dt, and end_dt as my start and stop timestamps.  create_dt has system::startdate for the variable.  How do I get the SCD stage in SSIS to recognize these, and add the timestamps as necessary, whether or not a record in the target table has that PK already?

Thanks.

UPDATE #1: PK was meant to be BK.  PK is autonumber.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments at the moment...

I think you have a couple of misunderstandings here.

1. If by PK you mean primary key, a primary key defines the uniqueness of each row. By definition you cannot have duplicate keys (without cheating!), or unless this is a foreign key from another table? How have you declared the business key within the SCD wizard?
2. You say you have set all the fields to "Historical"? yet you don't want new rows when the SCD finds a match on "PK"? Historical attributes will keep a history of all the previous records, so your records will be added as new in the SCD wizard. If you don't want new records, and you want existing records to be updated then you would need to use Changing Attribute.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i need new records. Type 2. I do not want updates.  I do have a business key.  I just wrote my example wrong. The pk represents the business key inn this example.

Answer (score 0):

This will be easier to handle in SQL than it will in SSIS.  The SCD component will load the existing rows into memory before the dataflow starts.  As rows are evaluated, this recordset it not updated, so if you see two records for the same businesskey, they will be treated the same way.

An approach that will perform better and be easier to understand and maintain would be as follows:

1. Insert all the rows from the source into a staging table
2. Call a proc in the package that will update the dimension table
3. In the proc:

   1. Insert new SCD rows.  The query should compare the target and staging table to determine which rows have not been seen before
   2. Insert historical SCD rows.  This query should again compare the tables to fetch the correct records.  You might use a window function to calculate start and end dates.